# Question About Turing Machine Computability

Tags: automata-theory, turing-machines, regular-language, regular-expressions, church-turing-thesis

If p is a Turing machine then L(p) = {x | p(x) = yes}.

Let A = {p | p is a Turing machine and L(p) is a finite set}.

Is A computable? Justify your answer.

So I'm trying to figure out how to solve this practice problem and was wondering if the following solution would be valid for this question.

Yes, A is computable, here is an algorithm that solves it.

If P is a turing machine then L(P) is the set of all strings so that, when you run P on input x, P eventually stops and accepts x.

is x in P?(P, x)

1. Run P(x)
2. if x is a member of P,
3. answer yes
4. else
5. answer no